# Connection issues when visiting my website

Tags: networking, internet, troubleshooting

I tried to visit my website today only to find that I couldn't connect to it. I decided to check out my web server to see if I could fix the issue, but I don't 100% know what I'm doing and am a bit stuck.

I updated my server and apache seems to be running fine. I can connect to the internet while on said server and my files seem to be in tact but...when I attempt to connect to my site, I get the error 'The website at (my IP address) )seems to be unavailable. The precise error was:

Could not connect: No route to host."

Anybody know what's going on, or where a good starting point could be?

Comment: Is your server behind a residential grade router?

Comment: What is the website address?

Comment: @DavidPostill: it's not on the internet, just local to my network.

Comment: @Tyson: Yes. It's pretty old too.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should find out the speed shown by ISP, the distance between the computer and router, whether there have been some essential setting changes.
1.  You should check the settings of network interface card it should be set “receive IP-addresses automatically”
2.  You should connect using LAN and check your speed here speedtest.net 
3.  If the first two steps don’t work and your speed is still low, you should connect cable right to the computer and check the speed again
4.  If the speed changes and become appropriate, it means you should deal with the router. 
It the speed is the same low, you should ask the provider to do extra test.